# Print output of `\write18` in the log file

Tags: shell-escape

When running commands like:

```
\immediate\write18{ls}
```

in the command line, I can see the output in the command line directly in the terminal, which is practical for instance to get error messages. Unfortunately, this is not written in the .log file, so for instance in TexStudio, the log just prints:

```
runsystem(ls)...executed.
```

Which is not really helpful for debugging. Is it possible to force LaTeX to print the output of `\write18` directly in the log file? Ideally, I'd like a solution as OS-independent as possible as I need to implement it for a library.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\writecommandtolog}{m}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { ls~-1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \exp_args:NV \iow_log:n \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\writecommandtolog{ls}

\stop
```

The relevant part of the log is, in my experiment,

```
aa.tex cc.tex tolog.log tolog.tex xyz.tex
```

Adorn at will.

Comment: Thanks, but the main issue with this is that I cannot use quotes inside the command while I do use quotes… "Note that quote characters (") cannot be used inside the shell command" :-\

Comment: @tobiasBora I'm not sure what the problem is: you ***cannot*** use quotes in `\write18` to begin with.

Comment: What do you mean? If I create a file `my file.txt`, then `\immediate\write18{cat "my file.txt"}` will work but not `\immediate\write18{cat my file.txt}`. I am actually using quotes here, and got no error so far: https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/blob/da824c945010e3827ba76a055aeb6f37862915f4/robust-externalize.sty#L2801

Comment: On the other hand, with your example I get an error `! LaTeX Error: Quotes in shell command 'cat "my file.txt"'.`

Comment: @tobiasBora On Windows, one needs quotes to deal with file names with spaces; as such, to ensure cross-platform compatibility, we normalise them in all shell commands

Comment: @JosephWright Well, on Linux you also need quotes to deal with file names no? So what is the "good", cross-platform way of using `\sys_get_shell` with file names that might contain spaces?

Comment: @tobiasBora I was not precise in my previous comment, sorry; the primitive syntax for getting into TeX the output of a shell command is `\input|"<command>"` and you cannot use quotes in the `<command>`. Whether this has been a good choice, I pass; anyway there it is.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150320/discussion-on-answer-by-egreg-print-output-of-write18-in-the-log-file); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.